# Trying to display an object

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object

I'm working on a project that groups transactions by month but running into some trouble. For some reason my table just outputs the following: "[object Object]" If anyone could point out what I'm missing I would appreciate it! :D

This is the ts file that groups the array into months and then displays them:

```
export class TableJsonComponent implements OnInit {
  transactions: any = [];

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpClient.get("assets/transactions.json").subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.transactions = data;
    });
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    const monthName = item =>
      moment(item.transaction_date, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("MMMM");
    this.httpClient.get("assets/transactions.json").subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.transactions = _.chain(this.transactions)
        .groupBy(monthName)
        .mapValues(items => _.map(items, "customer.name"))
        .value();_.map(Object, 'data');
    });

    const byMonth = _.chain(this.transactions)
      .groupBy(monthName)
      .mapValues(items => _.map(items, "customer.name"))
      .value();_.map(Object, 'data');
    console.log(byMonth);
    return byMonth;
    console.log(this.transactions);
  }
}
```

This is the table that shows all of the data from the array:

```
<table class="table" *ngFor="let month of transactions | keyvalue">
    <tr>
        <th>{{month.key}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="table" *ngFor="let customer of month.value">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{customer}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this is the Json file I'm grabbing the values from:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "billing_stage_net_value": 15.160000000000,
      "customer": {
        "name": "Harbour Cafe"
      },
      "id": 1142,
      "transaction_date": "2019-10-22T13:56:11.971643+00:00"
    },
    {
      "billing_stage_net_value": 51.000000000000,
      "customer": {
        "name": "Crisp Sandwich Cafe"
      },
      "id": 1143,
      "transaction_date": "2019-10-22T13:57:24.375087+00:00"
    },
    {
      "billing_stage_net_value": 13.500000000000,
      "customer": {
        "name": "Crisp Sandwich Cafe"
      },
      "id": 1144,
      "transaction_date": "2019-10-22T13:57:24.375087+00:00"
    },
    {
      "billing_stage_net_value": 12.000000000000,
      "customer": {
        "name": "Crisp Sandwich Cafe"
      },
      "id": 1145,
      "transaction_date": "2019-10-22T13:57:24.375087+00:00"
    },
    {
      "billing_stage_net_value": 17.000000000000,
      "customer": {
        "name": "Crisp Sandwich Cafe"
      },
      "id": 1149,
      "transaction_date": "2019-10-22T16:52:16.108941+00:00"
    },
    {
      "billing_stage_net_value": 13.540000000000,
      "customer": {
        "name": "Harbour Cafe"
      },
      "id": 1136,
      "transaction_date": "2019-10-22T11:39:46.748688+00:00"
    },
    {
      "billing_stage_net_value": 12.640000000000,
      "customer": {
        "name": "Harbour Cafe"
      },
      "id": 1137,
      "transaction_date": "2019-10-22T11:39:46.748688+00:00"
    },
    {
      "billing_stage_net_value": 3.000000000000,
      "customer": {
        "name": "Harbour Cafe"
      },
      "id": 1138,
      "transaction_date": "2019-10-22T11:39:46.748688+00:00"
    },
    {
      "billing_stage_net_value": 9.000000000000,
      "customer": {
        "name": "Harbour Cafe"
      },
      "id": 1141,
      "transaction_date": "2019-10-22T13:56:11.971643+00:00"
    },
    {
      "billing_stage_net_value": 81.000000000000,
      "customer": {
        "name": "Daphne's Diner"
      },
      "id": 1146,
      "transaction_date": "2019-10-22T13:58:22.839725+00:00"
    },
    {
      "billing_stage_net_value": 28.220000000000,
      "customer": {
        "name": "Daphne's Diner"
      },
      "id": 1147,
      "transaction_date": "2019-10-22T13:58:22.839725+00:00"
    },
    {
      "billing_stage_net_value": 3.900000000000,
      "customer": {
        "name": "Daphne's Diner"
      },
      "id": 1148,
      "transaction_date": "2019-10-22T13:58:22.839725+00:00"
    },
    {
      "billing_stage_net_value": 20.310000000000,
      "customer": {
        "name": "Harbour Cafe"
      },
      "id": 1140,
      "transaction_date": "2019-10-22T13:56:11.971643+00:00"
    }
  ],
  "message": "",
  "metadata": {},
  "success": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table class="table"  *ngFor="let month of transactions | keyvalue">
    <tr >
        <th>{{month.key}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr  >
        <td  >
            <table class="table" *ngFor="let d of month.value">
                <tr>
                  <td><strong>id:</strong> {{d.id}}</td>
                    <td><strong>billing_stage_net_value:</strong> {{d.billing_stage_net_value}}</td>
                     <td><strong>customer: </strong>{{d.customer.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ix4zeu?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: OKay, that looks like it worked but it still doesn't display the Month name like it does when I pull the data from a hardcoded array.

Here's the problem remade: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkpyvp?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.html

Comment: Try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bw6xd1?file=src/app/table-json/table-json.component.html

Comment: I want to have the month in the header and the customers for each month nested underntath. Doing it that way adds the month each time rather than grouping them together.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 <table class="table" id="customers">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let customer of transactions[0] | keyvalue ">{{customer.key}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let customer of transactions">
            <td>{{customer.billing_stage_net_value | date}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.customer.name}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.id}}</td>
            <td>{{customer.transaction_date | date}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ijseau?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: That only lists the dates but it doesnt keep the month grouping as I have in my demo